# Изменение яркости дисплея в зависимости от освещения

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Нужно на основе данных полученных от датчика света менять яркость дисплея, помогите пожалуйста.

```
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent s)
        {
            if (s.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Light)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Датчик света" + s.Values[0]);

            }

        }
```